# Using Celery with Django to access a rate limited RESTful API

Tags: django, rest, celery, rate-limiting

Just wondering whether my idea is unnecessarily complicated and if there is an easier/better way.

I'm planning on using Celery to send requests and retrieve data from a rate limited RESTful API (10 requests per 10 seconds). This was the solution to an issue I came upon earlier where my self written API wrapper, which handled the rate limit internally, would be instanced for each view and therefore incorrectly handle the rate limit.

Edit (More details):
I'm creating a website that has to request data from a RESTful API (namely League of Legends' API). I've written a python wrapper for the API, which deals with the rate limit imposed by the API by counting the requests made per interval and waiting. However when it came to implementing my wrapper into my Django project, I realised that creating an instance of my wrapper class when I need to utilise the API would break the rate limit handling of my wrapper as each instance would have a separate count of requests.

The solution I thought of, that may or may not be too complex, is to use Celery to 'run' a single instance of my wrapper that every view would use. This seemed relatively 'out of the way' for a idea that seemed pretty simple. Perhaps there is a simpler way to carry a single instance of a class throughout.

Comment: Don't understand your question. Please give more details / what you tried.

Comment: It sounds reasonable, but as is it is quite broad.

Comment: Edit'ed with additional information, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

***Late answer but could help others looking for something similar***, IMHO using `Celery` to manage a single instance of your API wrapper for handling rate-limited API requests can be a viable solution, but I think it's a kinda complex, and over-engineered solution.
I have worked with something like the one mentioned here and my approach was using the *`Singleton pattern`* in your Python `API` wrapper class. This pattern ensures that only one instance of the class is created and shared among all the views. Thus,  you maintain a single instance to handle rate limiting without the need for Celery. Here's a simple example:

```
class MyAPIWrapper:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(MyAPIWrapper, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls._instance.init()
        return cls._instance

    def init(self):
        # your API here

# Usage:
api_instance = MyAPIWrapper()
```

#### Another solution (got from googling and reading on Medium):

- In the Django framework, you can create a custom middleware that initializes and stores the API wrapper instance in the request object. This way, you can access the same instance throughout the required views. In this way, you keep things within the Django framework without the need for external tools or libraries like Celery.
- Also, you can work around with Django's caching framework to store the API wrapper instance, ensuring that it's available across multiple views. You can use Django's cache to store the API instance with a cache timeout, ensuring it's recreated if needed.
  Here some code:

```
# api_wrapper.py
class RateLimitedAPIWrapper:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(RateLimitedAPIWrapper, cls).__new__(cls)
            # rate limiting logic here
        return cls._instance

# middleware.py
from .api_wrapper import RateLimitedAPIWrapper

class APIMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.api_wrapper = RateLimitedAPIWrapper()

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Make the API wrapper available to all views via request
        request.api_wrapper = self.api_wrapper
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'yourapp.middleware.APIMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```